# Number of ways to place a L-shaped Tetromino in 2*n rectangle

Tags: combinatorics

Let n € N and consider a 2 X n
checkerboard. Let a(n) be the
number of ways to place L-shaped
tiles of size 4 on the checkerboard.
For example,
n = 4 -> a(4) = 11.
(a) (1 points) Find a(5)
(b) (7 points) Find a recurrence relation for a(n).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Also, these will help you format math here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Comment: It is not clear what "the number of ways to place..." you are referring to. Judging from $a(4) = 11$, you are placing an unspecified number $k$ of L-tetromino into the checkboard w/o overlap and you want the sum of number of configurations over all $k = 0,1,2,\ldots$. Is that correct?

Comment: @achille hui yes your understanding is correct